# How to change compact style DatePicker popover placement/alignment in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui

Is there a way to make the popover center aligned with the DatePicker?

```
    var body: some View {
        VStack (alignment: .center){
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Toggle("", isOn: $showDatePicker)
                    .padding()
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 30)
                Spacer()
            }
            HStack {
                if showDatePicker {
                    DatePicker("", selection: $selectedDate, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
                }
            }
            .frame(width: 50, height: 30)
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
        .background(Color.white)
        .cornerRadius(16)
        .shadow(radius: 8)
        .frame(width: 380, height: 530)
    }
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't think you can. You can use `.datePickerStyle(.graphical)` and put it inside the popover / overlay _you_ create, and then you can place it where you want.

Comment: @rapiddevice thanks! I can give this workaround a try